# Storing results in var returned from stored procedure which uses temp table in mvc Entityframework showing error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I have Created Stored Procedure which uses Temp Table to store some fields and update those fields based on condition.

when i import this stored procedure in report data set fields are not displayed..
this i got solved this problem using illogical code

```
IF 1=0 BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

but when i call this stored procedure like

```
var details = db.storedprocedure(param1,param2,param3);
```

i got error use data table or `IEnumerable` to store data
and i tried to store in data table and `IEnumerable` It shows error `cannot convert int to Ienumerable or datatable`

Comment: What is `obj.storedprocedure`? I don't know of such a method in the FCL and it doesn't conform to C# naming conventions. Showing actual code will help us help you.

Comment: that is object of dbcontext or  obj created from entity element